# Can an instance_method of a Module be invoked?

Tags: ruby

This is strictly theoretical.

```
module BleeTest
  def meth
    puts 'foo'
  end
end
```

This code runs without error, but is it ever possible the invoke the method "meth"?

It seems to me that "meth" is an instance method of a module which cannot be instantiated.  But then why is this construct allowed by the interpreter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can mix `BleeTest` into an object:

```
o = Object.new
o.extend BleeTest

o.meth
# foo
```

Or you can mix `BleeTest` into a class:

```
class C
  include BleeTest
end

o = C.new

o.meth
# foo
```

In fact, the first form can also be expressed in terms of the second form:

```
o = Object.new

class << o
  include BleeTest
end

o.meth
# foo
```

That *is*, after all, the *whole point* of modules in Ruby: to serve as mixins in order to compose objects and classes.

Comment: unfortunately you can only `bind` the method to an instance of a subclass of `BleeTest`. `m.bind(o).call #=> TypeError: bind argument must be an instance of BleeTest`. So doing this works fine: `o.extend(BleeTest); m.bind(o).call #=> foo`

Comment: Thank you, that helps to clarify some gem source code I am reading through.

Comment: @banister: you're right. Looking through my IRb history, I had a copy&paste error while testing the above code: somehow, a stray `include BleeTest` ended up in my clipboard. `include Foo` at the top-level mixes `Foo` into `Object`, which is why it worked when I tested it. This goes to show: always test with a fresh environment!